# Unity set SplitApplicationBinary programmatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to set Settings "SplitApplicationBinary" in PlayerSettings programmatically? I did not find this field in PlayerSettings class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the line `APKExpansionFiles: 0` to `APKExpansionFiles: 1` in `ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset` file. With some YAML parser or just replacing it verbatim (just mind the spaces at the line start).

Unity will check this file every time you build - you are free to edit it in between.

Comment: Thanks, I should using PlayerSettings.Android.useAPKExpansionFiles